# Discord.js Problems With Default Command in Switch

Tags: switch-statement, discord.js, default

So I'm trying to make a discord bot, and I am trying to set up a way to get the bot to ask to use the help command when an input isn't defined, but when I set the default in the switch statement, it just repeats itself over and over, @ing itself with the text inputted.

```
switch(args[0]){
    case 'ping':
        message.channel.send('pong!');
        break;
    case 'rockLink':
        message.channel.send('') //text here, deleted to protect link
        break;
    case 'info':
        if(args[1] === 'description'){
            message.channel.send('I am eventually going to play rock music, for now I do random stuff.')
        }else if(args[1] === 'author'){
            message.channel.send('I was made by IAmAGreenFlamingo')
        }else if(args[1] === 'version'){
            message.channel.send('This bot is in version ' + version)
        }else{
            message.channel.send('Invalid Argument, please use !help info to see all valid arguments!')
        }
        break;
    case 'help':
        if(args[1] === 'info'){
            message.reply('Arguments for !info: description, author.')
        }else{
            message.reply('The commands so far are: !ping, !rockLink, and !info (use !help info for arguments)!')
        }
        break;
    default:
        message.reply('Invalid Argument, please use !help to see all commands!')
        break;
}
```

Comment: Also forgot to mention that I am new to coding, sorry.

Comment: It perfectly works for me, The issue is from your args[0]. Can you send me the line where you create your argument array?

Comment: @Dorian349 here it is: `let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" "):` Aci already posted a fix, but I would still like to learn how you would tackle this problem! Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good practice to ignore bots and DMs for commands. Add something like this at the top of your `.on('message')` statement:

```js
if(message.author.bot || !message.guild) return //ignores bot messages and pms
```

This should also stop it from answering to itself.

Another option is to replace the `message.reply`s with `message.send`s so it doesn't tag itself or anyone else.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I am setting the bot to `message.reply` on some parts because I want the bot to notify the person that sent the command. Sorry if my grammar is bad.

Comment: So after using this, the bot responds with the message I coded in on any message sent, and the normal commands don't work.

Comment: How are you listening to normal commands? Could you edit your question to include some of that code, too?

Comment: Please clarify. I am really new to coding, so I don't necessarily understand what you mean by how I am listening to normal commands. Thank you!

Comment: If you want I can post my full code, with some things missing of course, if that helps at all

Comment: Most people have declared a variable like "const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();". Are or are you using message.content.startswith(), or something else?